# Some websites not reachable using cellular data but working perfectly using Wifi

Tags: google, networking, connection-issues, xiaomi, mobile-network

I a have a Xiaomi mi 9 se phone and I am not able to access some websites using their IP adress. To give you some context, I have some servers I wish I can access but it not possible, I receive a ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE in chrome for android when using cellular data but the same IP address works fine using Wifi. Using another phone (Google pixel) the same address can be accessed without any problems using cellular data.

I though it could be a carrier issue but I tried the sim card from the Google Pixel putting it in my Xiaomi phone and still it does not work.

I tried tweaking with DNS configuration but still nothing.

Do you have any idea on what can be the cause of this problem ?

Comment: Are you talking about IPv4 (four numbers connected by dots) or IPv6 (multiple numbers connected by colons) addresses? If it the latter your cellular provider might not yet support it. If you enter the IP address then the DNS configuration is not used at all.

Comment: Yes it is IPv4 format. Indeed, you are absolutely right about the DNS ans IP addresses, my bad.

Comment: Can you give us the first three numbers of the IP address? May be the address belongs to a subnet that was originally restricted but later because of the small number of remaining IPv4 addresses was opened for use but your cell provider still thinks it is restricted.

Comment: In fact any ip address will not work when I try to access it from my phone. For exemple I can't access cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 IP address using cellular data while accessing using wifi is not a problem. Also if I put my SIM card in my google pixel phone, I can access any IP address normally.

Comment: [This](https://www.digitbin.com/err_address_unreachable-error-fix/) source says that `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` means a DNS resolution problem. Can you somehow find a way to use a different DNS? 8.8.8.8 works often much better.